# Returning astronauts. Mandated race mixing after race wars

Tags: story-identification, novel, astronauts

The novel is about astronauts that return to earth after hundreds of years to find race wars have mandated people can only mate with different races so ultimately everyone is the same.
Read in late 70s or 80s-one of the astonauts was a black man and they didnt exist anymore. Vaguely recall “proc” being a derogatory term referring to procreation.

Comment: "Tonight The Stars Revolt!" by Gardner F. Fox, collected in the Brian Aldiss anthology *Galactic Empires*, had a throwaway line - nevertheless highlighted in Aldiss's introduction - about a post-war Earth "compelling interracial wedlock and births".

Comment: If they can only mate "outside your race" how do they manage when they are all the same?

Comment: _Shhh... @user108131, don't try to apply logic..._

Answer (score 7):

Could this be *[Ghost](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/96973)* by Piers Anthony?

> This novel is set in a near-future dystopia where the earth is suffering from an energy shortage so severe that the world government has attempted to slow population growth -- and thus slow the rate of energy consumption -- by passing laws forbidding procreation between members of the same race. In order to marry someone of your own race, you must agree to undergo voluntary sterilization.

There's mention of prok (or proc) as a swear word

> *Prok-that word again. But this time it was in context. Prok-proc-procreation. A new four-letter term, signifying illicit reproduction, similar to the one he had been raised with.*